# what is the differrent bracket notation and dot notation in javascript object

Tags: javascript

learn javascript from freecodecamp, when i reach object, they teach about `bracket notation` and `dot notation`, when i use `dot notation` in `return obj.checkProp` like below code

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
  return obj.checkProp;
}
else return "Not Found";

  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "pet"));
```

the return is undefied
but when i use `bracket notation` in `return obj[checkProp]`

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
  return obj[checkProp];
}
else return "Not Found";

  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "pet"));
```

it `return` kitten.
my question is why the `dot` is not working but the `bracket` is working

Comment: Haven't you demonstrated the difference with your example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: because `checkProp` isn't a property of `obj`, but contains it's name. `obj.pet` is equivalent to `obj['pet']`. This is exactly the same than `var foo = 'bar'; console.log(foo);` it displays `'bar'`, not `'foo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you want to check for the value contained in the variable `checkProp` rather than for the value `checkProp`.

`obj[checkProp]` is equivalent to `obj.pet` in your example whereas `obj.checkProp` is equivalent to `obj['checkProp']`